# If $a(p+q)^2+2bpq+c=0$ and $a(p+r)^2+2bpr+c=0$ then find $qr$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

If it is given that: $$a(p+q)^2+2bpq+c=0\\a(p+r)^2+2bpr+c=0$$ then find $qr$.

I dont have any clues on how to begin. I tried subtracting, but won't take it anywhere. This looks like a hidden quadratic but i cannot figure it out! Please give me some clue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Clearly, $q,r$ are the two roots of $$0=a(p+t)^2+2bpt+c=at^2+2tp(a+b)+ap^2+c$$

Comment: Thank you I understand it!

Comment: So the answer is $\frac{ap^2+c}{a}$ ?

Comment: @akhmeteni, See https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/

Answer (score 2):

I think it's impossible to calculate $qr$. Try $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: Yes you are right! But answer is given same as we get from lab's answer, so probably they forgot to exclude your case!

Comment: @Michael, What if $$ac\ne0?$$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee For $ac\neq0$ your solution is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

If $a\not=0$, then lab bhattacharjee's answer gives

$$qr={ap^2+c\over a}$$

If $a=0$ and $bp\not=0$, then we have $q=r=-c/(2bp)$, and thus

$$qr={c^2\over4b^2p^2}$$

Finally, if $a=bp=0$, then we must have $c=0$ as well and, as in Michael Rozenberg's answer, $q$ and $r$ can be anything, so $qr$ cannot be calculated.